# Change window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth to device pixel size

Tags: javascript, window, resize

I want to change `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to a specific size in device pixels, **not CSS pixels**.

I tried this:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if (window.confirm("Do you want to change this window's inner Size?")) {
    let x = window.prompt("Width:");
    let y = window.prompt("Height:");
    let r = window.devicePixelRatio;
    window.innerWidth = x / r;
    window.innerHeight = y / r;
  }
});
```

but the size of the new window doesn't match the given values.

For example, if I enter 1000 for width and height each, I get a window with an inner height of 1005 and an inner width of 989 device pixels.

Any idea how I can change the inner size of a window precisely?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) `window.innerHeight` is a read-only property.

you can try [resizeBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeBy) or [resizeTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo)

Comment: This appears to be more of a comment than an answer. It tells the OP why they cannot use `window.innerHeight` to set the window height, but doesn't tell them what to use instead.